# Command documentation in jquery-terminal with authentication token

Tags: jquery-terminal

I'm creating a jquery terminal with server side authentication by following the example [JSON-RPC with authentication](http://terminal.jcubic.pl/examples.php#json_rpc_demo). It works well, but when I type "help" to get information on a particular command, the authentication token is included as the first parameter. I'm worried that this may confuse the users or make them think they have to type a token into the terminal.

For example, in the [demo](http://terminal.jcubic.pl/rpc-demo.html) for the example, typing "help ls" returns:

```
> help ls
ls token path 
list directory if token is valid
```

Is there any way I can configure jquery-terminal to filter out the token, so that typing "help ls" returns something like this?

```
> help ls
ls path 
list directory if token is valid
```

I've been trying to work out if this can be done by writing a custom "help" command, but am not sure how to do this while still using the documentation in the JSON-RPC response.

Comment: I've look at the source code and correctly to overwrite build in help command is to create your own help JSON-RPC method, I've created an issue on github to remove first argument in help, if rpc have login. https://github.com/jcubic/jquery.terminal/issues/357

Comment: The fix is in devel branch will be in version 1.11.0

Comment: The fix works great - thank you!